# How can I find if there are 6 consecutive descending numbers in a List?

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have to retrieve a List of objects that will then be passed as data for a visual chart. When iterating through the List, I need to check if there are 6 consecutive objects that have a decreasing value for the ChartVal property. If this is the case, then each of those objects must have their DataPointColour set to 'Red', otherwise, 'Black'.

```
public class ChartData
{
  public int ChartVal {get; set;}
  public string ChartColour {get; set;}
  //Other properties
}

IList<ChartData> dataForChart = new List<ChartData>();
var data = _myDataService.GetChartData();

foreach(var item in data)
{
  //Pseudo code
  //Determine if current item.ChartVal is less than previous item.ChartVal
  //If so, set ChartColour to Red, but only if the current item.ChartVal is part
  //of a consecutive group of 6 decreasing values

dataForChart.Add(new ChartData { ChartVal = item.Value, ChartColour = 'Red' });

//Else, ChartColour is Black

dataForChart.Add(new ChartData { ChartVal = item.Value, ChartColour = 'Black' });

}
```

I'm struggling to know where to start with this, mainly because the Object ChartColour must be Red, but only if it is part of a consecutive group of descending Chart.

Examples:

If var data contains [10,9,8,7,6,5,5,6,7,8], then the sequence of numbers 10,9,8,7,6,5 would be highlighted in Red on the Chart, and the numbers 5,6,7,8 would be Black.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help with this.

Many thanks.

Comment: You need to keep items in a sublist if they are smaller than the previous. Each time you encounter an item without a lower value, clear the sublist and start again with the current item. Once the sublist contains six items, set their colour. The reason people have trouble with stuff like this is because they try to think in code instead of thinking in logic and then implementing that logic in code. Don't try to write any code until you already know what it has to do, i.e. not just the end result but the steps to get their.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - Thank you, this advice was most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think a bit about your problem. First of all you need to compare two sequential items. Then you need to check if the two items are descending, and some method to count the number of sequential descending numbers. If you ascend and the count is higher than 6 you have found a range you need to color red, and reset the count.

For example:

```
public static IEnumerable<(int Index, int Length)> GetDescendingRanges(
    IEnumerable<int> values,
    int minSequenceLength)
{
    
    using var iter = values.GetEnumerator();
    if (!iter.MoveNext())
    {
        yield break;
    }
    var previousValue = iter.Current;
    var currentIndex = 1;
    var sequenceStartIndex = 0;
    var sequenceLength = 0;
    while (iter.MoveNext())
    {
        var currentValue = iter.Current;
        sequenceLength++;
        if (currentValue < previousValue)
        {
            if (sequenceLength == 0)
            {
                sequenceStartIndex = currentIndex-1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (sequenceLength >= minSequenceLength)
            {
                yield return ( sequenceStartIndex, sequenceLength);
            }
            sequenceLength = 0;
            sequenceStartIndex = currentIndex;
        }

        currentIndex++;
        previousValue = currentValue;
    }
}
```

This should give you a sequence of ranges that need to be colored red. The simplest option is likely to create all your chartData as black, and then loop over the list and color all the descending parts red.

```
var values = data.Select(item => item.Value);
var chartData = values.Select(v=> new ChartData(){ ChartVal = v, ChartColour = "Black" }).ToArray(); 
foreach(var (offset, length) in GetDescendingRanges(values , 6)){
   for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
       chartData[offset + i].ChartColour = "Red";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about creating a ColourState class that you use instead of a string. This way you can monitor the downward trend and if its more than 6 you can update the colour property of the state class and all items part of that set will change.

See example below.

```
public class ChartData
{
  public int ChartVal {get; set;}
  public ColourState ChartColour {get; set;}
  //Other properties
}

public class ColourState
{
    public string Colour { get; set; } = "Black";
}

IList<ChartData> dataForChart = new List<ChartData>();
var data = _myDataService.GetChartData();

int previousValue = int.MinValue;
int count = 0;
var state = new ColourState();
foreach(var item in data)
{
  if(item.Value < previousValue){
    count++;
  }
  else
  {
    count = 0;
    state = new ColourState();
  }

  if(count >= 6){
    state.Colour = "Red";
  }

  var chartData = new ChartData
  {
    ChartVal = item.Value,
    ChartColour = state
  };

    dataForChart.Add(chartData);
    previousValue = item.Value;
}
```